# Invalid namespace "rootvirtualization" on Hyper-V 2012

Tags: powershell, hyper-v-2012

Running the following command on a fresh Hyper-V 2012 server:

```
get-wmiobject -namespace “rootvirtualization” -Query “select * from Msvm_ConcreteJob”
```

produces this errorerror:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace "rootvirtualization"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Namespace "rootvirtualization" -Query "Select * from Msvm_concret ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I'm lost as to what the issue would be, shouldn't this namespace be part of a standard Hyper-V install? Is there some powershell module I need to install?

Comment: Is that a literal copy/paste of your code? Those aren't normal double quotes in the `Get-WmiObject` command. If it is copied [from a blog post](http://tritoneco.com/2013/01/25/view-progress-of-hyper-v-snapshot-merge/) try: `Get-WmiObject -Namespace "rootvirtualization" -Query "select * from Msvm_ConcreteJob"` instead.

Comment: Nicely spotted jscott, I did get the command from a blog (and pasted it in the question), but I'm typing it in manually on the server. I just tried to copy/paste your version, same result.

Comment: [This Technet magazine post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722740.aspx) shows the namespace as `root\Virtualization` which makes more sense to me.  Could you try `Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\virtualization" -Query "select * from Msvm_ConcreteJob"`  Here is [a TechNet blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/benp/archive/2008/01/29/listing-wmi-namespaces-installed-on-a-host.aspx) which details how to list the available namespaces. If the above command fails, check the namespaces to see what's available.

Comment: That did it! Thanks jscott -- please add an answer and I'll flag it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a backslash is missing from the namespace path.  Rather than `"rootvirtualization"` the path should be `"root\virtualization"`

UPDATE: For 2012 R2 the namespace is `"root\virtualization\v2"`

Comment: For 2012 R2 the namespace is "root\virtualization\v2"

Comment: underrated comment ^